# Использование указателей в map (C++)

Tags: c++, указатели, map

Задача звучит следующим образом: разбить вектор на равные по количеству элементов отрезки. Вектор размера N, надо разделить на M < N отрезков. В случае необходимости (если отрезки равными не получаются), можно нарезать не весь вектор, не учитывая начало/конец вектора до/после нарезанной части.
В любую структуру данных сохранить адрес начала и конца каждого такого отрезка.

Не уверен что я сделал корректно, но я решил делать через map с набором из двух указателей содержащих ссылки на начало и конец соответственно, для каждого экземпляра.

При компиляции выдает следующую ошибку:

> Вызвано необработанное исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
>   std::_Tree,std::allocator >,0> >::_Root(...) вернул 0x4.

Подобные задачи никогда не решал раньше, возможно сделал все в корне неправильно. Google ответа не дал, поэтому обращаюсь к сообществу.

```
std::map<int *, int *> PartsCut(std::map<int *, int *> Borders, std::vector<int> Vector, int N)
{
int i = N / 2;
while (i > 1)
{
    if (N % i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j = j + i)
        {
            Borders.insert(std::pair<int *, int *>(&Vector[j], &Vector[j + i - 1]));
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    else
        i--;
}
if (i == 1)
    return PartsCut(Borders, Vector, N - 1);
else        
    return Borders;
}
```

Comment: А вы уверены что "адреса" в данном случае - не индексы в векторе?

Comment: В коде? Протестил отдельно от функции, в формате – int *test = &Vector[2]; Отображается все корректно. Или вы о постановке задачи? Да, судя по всему вы правы и я перемудрил... Но все равно, мне самому интересно, как довести до ума задачу неправильно мной понятую.

Comment: Перепишите заново. На вход вектор, на выход - вектор структур, хранящих индекс начала и конца.

Comment: Что-то я у вас в коде прям совсем не вижу _M_, где он должен быть?

Comment: @StateItPrimitive _i_ - определяет количество элементов в каждом отрезке, _M_ мне в коде явно не нужен, т.к. по заданию надо просто записать начало и конец отрезка. А так, на выходе _M_ (по смыслу) - вывод всех экземпляров получившегося списка. Ну или можно выразить через _i_ - _M = N / i_. При вычислении оптимального размера отрезка, мы в начале принимаем _M_ за 2, потом уменьшаем размер отрезка, и следовательно увеличиваем их количество.

Comment: В что здесь вообще делает `std::map` и откуда он взялся? Поисковых операций по `std::map` я у вас в коде не вижу - только вставки, причем уникальные (т.е. отсеивание одинаковых вставок - не нужно). Сортированности результата тоже нигде не требуется. Так откуда возникла идея использовать `std::map`? Зачем мапить начало отрезка на конец отрезка??? Объясните, а то я спать не смогу.

Comment: Отдельно стоит напомнить, что элемент `std::map<int *, int *>` имеет тип `std::pair<int * const, int *>`, а не `std::pair<int *, int *>`, как вы неверно полагаете. По этой причине, если вы хотите сами конструировать элементы `std::map`, то рекомендуется прсто использовать тип `std::map<>::value_type`, а не заниматься рукописным выписыванием какого-то `std::pair<>`, да еще и со скрытыми ошибками.

Comment: @AnT Ну, вы прям жестко закритиковали, основная идея, по которой человек хотел использовать _map_ вроде интуитивно понятна: он хотел минимизировать используемую память и все в этом духе (наверное, университетское задание, а там любят такое практиковать, правда при современных характеристиках компьютеров это прям вообще не критично).

Comment: @AnT ну как откуда. Решил использовать. Не от большого ума возможно, а так скорее для практики, в учебных целях. Я возможно не понимаю, что плохого в использовании той или иной структуры, даже если я не использую весь ее функционал?

Comment: @StateItPrimitive да, вы по большому счету правы. Правда задание не университетское, а рабочее (делаю все подряд задания для собеседований, чтобы более емко понимать что требуется знать). А тяга к экономии да, имеет место быть. Разве это плохо?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Проблемы и пути решения**

Для начала рассмотрим основные ошибки, чтобы вы поняли как в дальнейшем избегать их:

*Проблема:* при передаче в функцию `PartsCut` вы все время копируете `std::vector<int> Vector`, а затем ссылаетесь на его элементы по указателю ( `Borders.insert(std::pair<int *, int *>(&Vector[j], &Vector[j + i - 1]));`), но когда вы выходите из функции, то экземпляр вашего `vector`'а умирает и указатели из `map`'ы указывают на невалидную (уже освобожденную) область памяти, т.е. при первом же разыменовании любого указателя из `map` за пределами функции ваша программа упадет.

*Решение проблемы:* передавайте вектор по ссылке причем с модификатором `const`, т.к. вы не планируете менять данный объект в функции, т.е. `const std::vector<int>& Vector` (да и вообще, если вы не планируете менять объект, который передаете параметром, в функции и он не является [примитивным типом данных](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc953fe1.aspx), то передавайте его через ссылку с модификатором `const`).

---

*Проблема:* в данном куске кода, вы легко можете обратиться к элементу за границами `vector`'а (а именно в `&Vector[j + i - 1])`, т.к у вас нигде не проверяется факт того, что `j + i - 1 < N`):

```
for (int j = 0; j < N; j = j + i)
{
   Borders.insert(std::pair<int *, int *>(&Vector[j], &Vector[j + i - 1]));
   i = 0;
}
```

*Решение проблемы:* я так понял, что подойдет такое:

```
int N = Vector.size(); // зачем передавать размер вектора, как параметр функции, если его можно получить непосредственно из вектора?
for (int j = 0; j < N; j = j + i)
{
   if (j + i - 1 < N)
      Borders.insert(std::pair<int *, int *>(&Vector[j], &Vector[j + i - 1]));
   else
      Borders.insert(std::pair<int *, int *>(&Vector[j], &Vector[N - 1]));
}
```

---

**Предложения по архитектуре реализации**

У вас `map` передается параметром и он же возвращается результатом работы функции, может быть есть возможность заранее посчитать `M` и передать его в функцию, и тогда не придется прибегать к рекурсии и так заморачиваться с параметрами?

То есть у вас будет один единственный параметр - это `const vector<int>& Vector` (ну или 2, если вы сумеет заранее посчитать `M`) и возвращать вы будете свою `map`'у, которую создадите в функции (*семантика rvalue перемещения* для *stl-контейнеров* со стандартными типами сделает свое дело, так что особо лишних затрат не будет).

---

В вашем коде вы делаете упор на тот факт, что `std::vector` имитирует работу *стандартного массива С*, а именно на то, что все данные из него хранятся в памяти сплошным куском (ну, или иначе я не понял зачем хранить указатель на первый и последний элемент `vector`'а в `map`'е, т.е. чтобы передвигаться по элементам, например, посредством *оператора ++*, примененного к указателю).

Если вы хотите сохранить основную идею реализации, но посредсвом *stl-контейнеров*, то можно заменить вашу `map`'у на что-то в духе:

```
typedef std::vector<int>::iterator VectorIterator;
typedef std::map<VectorIterator, VectorIterator> VectorIteratorMap;
```

А вообще, кажется более очевидным использовать какую-нибудь более интуитивно понятную структуру для хранения таких данных, например тот же `vector` или `list`, в котором хранить `pair`, в которых будет записана левая и правая граница из начального `vector`'а

```
typedef std::vector<int>::iterator VectorIterator;
typedef std::list<std::pair<VectorIterator, VectorIterator>> PairList;
```

Т.е. может получиться что-то в духе:

```
PairList PartsCut(const std::vector<int>& vector, int M)
{
   PairList result;
   for (VectorIterator leftBound = vector.begin(); vector.end() != leftBound; leftBound = leftBound + M)
   {
      VectorIterator rightBound = leftBound + M - 1;
      if (vector.end() != rightBound)
         result.push_back(std::make_pair(leftBound, rightBound));
      else
         result.push_back(std::make_pair(leftBound, vector.end() - 1));
   }
   return result;
}
```

Это просто набросок (не тестировал этот кусок кода).

Но если вам принципиальна оптимизация, то храните в `map`'е, а все эти штучки с итераторами - это скорее на любителя.

---

Все выше оговоренные варианты упираются во время жизни экземпляра контейнера `std::vector`, ссылка на который передается в функцию. В случае необходимости поддержания независимости результата работы функции от данного экземпляра контейнера, может быть, стоит хранить просто копии объектов из него в результирующем объекте, а не левую и правую границы диапазона элементов из `vector`'а?

---

Кстати, в плюсах нередко используется `UpperCamelCase` для наименования классов и `lowerCamelCase` — для наименования экземпляров классов для возможности быстро различать в коде классы/структуры от их экземпляров. Если вам приглянется такой стиль, то можете его использовать (это к слову про `Vector` и `Borders`), но также стоит заметить, что единого стандарта стиля кодирования (или рекомендаций, как на *java*) для *C++* нет.

---

Некоторые из предложений чисто субъективные, поэтому если что-то заинтересует, то можно попробовать развить идею (отпишите в комментариях если что, то подправлю ответ + судя по всему, тут не мало людей заинтересовались этой задачей, тем более смогут помочь).

Comment: _«что на плюсах обычно используется UpperCamelCase для наименования классов и lowerCamelCase»_ — это не так. К сожалению(счастью?) в C++ нет единого мнения насчёт именования, поэтому «обычно» к C++ вообще не применимо

Comment: @ixSci Да, это понятно, что единого стандарта (или рекомендаций, как у _java_) нет, но, как я замечал (по крайней мере в моей фирме и еще в 2ух фирмах моего города), довольно часто используется именно такой стиль.

Comment: а в самом C++ и boost используется другой стиль,  в windows-related библиотеках(WinRT к примеру) третий стиль. И всё это крупные разработки, крупные библиотеки. Поэтому, как я уже сказал, java style naming для C++ далеко не основной.

Comment: @ixSci Ну, тут не поспоришь, просто я хотел предложить один из стилей, который наглядно помогает различать классы/структуры от их экземпляров (сейчас попробую переформулировать в ответе).

Comment: Про "4 байта" категорически не согласен. С таким правилом и `double` и `long long` надо уже ссылками передавать, а это не есть гуд. Емнип, рекомендуют не 4 байта, а 4 `int`а. `1ин` - улыбнуло :)

Comment: @alexolut Думаю, что стоит и правда подправить на что-то в духе: все, кроме _примитивных типов данных_. С `1ин` - это да, ночью лень пересилила меня :)

Comment: @StateItPrimitive спасибо огромное за такой подробный ответ! Все приму к сведению, буду пробовать. Мне просто недостает практического опыта, а такие люди помогают его наверстать. Спасибо еще раз! Постараюсь не обесценивать ваше время, потраченное на совет, своей прокрастинацией) Жаль, пока репутации не хватает плюс поставить